# Does SVG foreignObject work only with static HTML?

Tags: d3.js, svg

As described on http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1424037, I have seen the foreignObject feature working only with statically inputted text. What happens if I try something like this:

```
svg.append("foreignObject")
      .attr("width", 400)
      .attr("height", 200)
   .append("xhtml:body")
      .style("font", "16px 'Helvetica Neue'")
      .html(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      })
```

Does the foreignObject feature work with data returned by functions?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Well, that does work. However one thing that needs to be taken care of is to replace html with text.


node.append("foreignObject")
         .attr("class", 'innerNode')
         .text(function (d) {
        return d.name; })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that does work. However one thing that needs to be taken care of is to replace .html with .text.

```
node.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("class", "innerNode")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.name; })
```